# What's the meaning of bold dashed vertical lines in chrome performance panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Does it mean the refresh timing of my monitor or the separator of frames? And if it is not the frame separator, where is the accurate beginning of a frame?